# What does it mean when a conductor puts their finger on their temple?

Tags: voice, intonation, conducting

What does it mean when a conductor puts their finger on their temple? That the singers need to pay more attention to intonation?

Comment: It's more likely to mean "Watch me!"

Comment: How many conductors have you witnessed doing this? Which one? Orchestra or choir?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meanings of conductors' gestures vary by conductor, and it depends on the physical specifics and musical circumstances. A few possibilities:

1. If the finger is closer to the ear, it could mean to listen more closely to each other.
2. If the finger is closer to the eyes, it could mean "watch me".
3. If the lyrics are about thinking or memory or such, it could be the conductor reminding the singers of the meaning of the lyrics.
4. It could be a cue to remember something discussed in rehearsal at that part of the music.
5. If the conductor is tapping the temple, it could be a way of cueing the pulse of the music.
6. Conductors will sometimes raise a finger to indicate that a cue is upcoming; perhaps this conductor touches the finger to temple.

Comment: So, almost anything...

Comment: @PiedPiper Indeed. Could have an itch or a headache. Could be a secret code devised by the illuminati.... :-)

Comment: 7. Someone there is crazy...

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention the singers, it could be a tuning fork. The conductor puts it next to the ear before the song starts, and then hums the starting note to the singer.

Please see the example at the very beginning of this video:

Comment: No, index finger, not tuning fork.

Comment: @Geremia it would then help if you provided a more concrete example. E.g. in the video I include one can easily overlook the tuning fork.